# What would be some winning strategies for a prime factorization lottery?

Tags: prime-factorization

With the hysteria surrounding the Powerball jackpot, I'm sure a lot of you have been thinking about the tiny odds of a lottery in which you have to match five or six numbers out of a small set (like 1 to 80).

What if there was a lottery in which a single even number between, say, $10^{10}$ and $10^{20}$ is chosen? But you don't have to match that number, you have to match more prime factors below $10^5$ than any other player. And you only get to choose five or six such primes. Let's say that for a particular drawing no player matches five primes but a few players match four primes. The player matching the larger primes would win the jackpot.

Such a lottery would be quite difficult for the average gambler. But for you who have studied prime factorization: what would be some winning strategies?

Comment: If it weren't for "larger primes win" it seems like you'd always choose the six lowest primes. I assume the likelihood of $p$ being a prime factor of $n$ is a function of the magnitude of $p$ (more likely as $p$ gets smaller) only; could anything else affect it?

Comment: The answer will depend on how many players there are, and how many entries each of the various players is buying.  But even the game for two players, one entry each is interesting. For concreteness, say the largest matching primes wins; if there is a tie there, then the largest second-highest match prime wins, and so forth.

Comment: And to ensure there is always a winner unless two players choose the identical set, define that if the two players match the same set of primes, then the same "dictionary ordering" win condition is applied to the non-matching primes.  For example, if A chose $\{2,3,5,7,11,13\}$ and B chose $\{2,3,5,7,11,17\}$ and the number picked is not divisible by 2, 3, 5, 7 or 11, then player B would win.